# Using System.Diagnostics, Performance Counters in a Windows Store App

Tags: c#, performancecounter, windows-store-apps

According to this page on msdn

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh441592.aspx

the System.Diagnostics namespace for windows store apps enable you to interact with performance counters.

To do this with a desktop application, I would normally do something like this:

```
PerformanceCounter cpu = new PerformanceCounter("Processor", "% Processor Time", "_Total");
PerformanceCounter ram = new PerformanceCounter("Memory", "Available MBytes");
```

And, then monitor these over time with NextValue()

However, when you create a windows store app - it seems the System.Diagnostics namespace doesn't contain the PerformanceCounter class.  I though this would be possible as the previously mentioned msdn page states you can interact with performance counters.

Does anybody know how to do CPU usage and memory usage performance counters in a windows store app?

Comment: It is a copy/paste mistake.  Do note that PerformanceCounter isn't actually listed on that page.  Under the hood it requires registry access to work, not permitted in a Windows Store app.